# How to detect and correct the Content-Type charset in email header in python?

Tags: python, email, character-encoding, shift-jis

What is the correct way to programatically detect and correct the `Content-Type` `charset` in an email header in python?

I have a 1000s of emails extracted to `.eml` (basically plain text) files and some are encoded `shift_jis`, but the charset in the email header doesn't mention this, so they don't display correctly in any email program. Adding in the `charset` manually to the `Content-Type` header corrects this.

Was:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; format=flowed
```

Needs to be:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="shift_jis"; format=flowed
```

What's the correct way to do this in python preserving the email body and other parts of the header?

Also, is there a way to detect which encoding, and only correct those with that encoding? I can't just convert all blindly, since some are `iso_2022_jp`, and those are already displaying correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [get_charset](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.get_charsets) you can get the pre-existing charset of a message.  Here's a sample:

```
from email import message_from_file
msg = message_from_file(open('path.eml'))
msg.get_charsets()
[None, 'gb2312', None]
```

With this approach you can loop through all messages, and using set_charset() set it to the ones that don't have it to the correct one.

Comment: Please do not post just a code sample, without any explanation or clarifications. Though technically correct and close to the OP's ask, your answer was tagged as "Low Quality" and in risk of deletion; had to edit it so it has the before-mentioned required properties.